# Assigning a range variable to row of current cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am having difficulty assigning the range of the active cell's row to a ranged variable. When I attempt to copy this variable in a range function call, I get the "Method range of object global failed" error. Any tips?

```
Sub GroupLanes()
Dim Origin, Destination, ODPair As String
Dim mainWorkbook As Workbook
Dim Index As Long
Dim IB, OB As Range

Set mainWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Index = 6

Range("G" & Index).Select
Origin = ActiveCell.Value

Debug.Print Origin

Range("H" & Index).Select
Destination = ActiveCell.Value

Debug.Print Destination

Range("AV" & Index).Select
ODPair = ActiveCell.Value

Debug.Print ODPair

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    Set IB = ActiveCell.EntireRow

    Range("AV6").Select
    ODPair = ActiveCell.Value

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        If (Mid(ODPair, 1, 5) = Destination And Mid(ODPair, 6, 5) = Origin) Then
            Set OB = ActiveCell.EntireRow

            Range(IB).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Index & ":" & "AV" & Index).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            Range(OB).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Index & ":" & "AV" & Index).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ODPair = ActiveCell.Value
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ODPair = ActiveCell.Value
            Debug.Print ODPair
        End If

    Loop

    Index = Index + 1

    Range("G" & Index).Select
    Origin = ActiveCell.Value

    Range("H" & Index).Select
    Destination = ActiveCell.Value

LoopEnd Sub
```

Comment: Too long code, I can't be bothered to read through it all. Which row produces the error? Also, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First things first; get rid of the `.Select` and `.Activate` It slows down the code.  For a great tutorial and explanation look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: I'm not really worried about scalability. This is an ad-hoc request that involves a very limited amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Range(IB).Copy
```

to

```
IB.Copy
```

IB is already a `Range` (kind of, see below) so when you call it in a range function, it's looking for a range with a name that's equal to what's in IB on your sheet.

In addition to Scott's tips about `Select` and `Activate`, be aware that

```
Dim IB, OB As Range
```

declares OB as a range, just like you want, but declares IB as a `Variant`. For more info, see this [Chip Pearson page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx) and scroll down to "Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement."